# svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/stacks/executive_trex \ executive_trex command is not working. Please help

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to install trex on my computer. But it is not being installed since the command above in the link http://wiki.ros.org/trex/Tutorials/Getting%20started
does not seem to be working, since I don't see any console output  for quite some time. Please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264147/svn-co-https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/stacks/executive_trex--executive_trex-command-is-not-working.-please-help./) by [Jaskirat Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/30755/jaskirat-singh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`code.ros.org` has long since been taken off-line.

You might want to search github for a fork / clone of that package.

---

Edit: a quick search doesn't show anything that seems related. `trex_executive` is also listed on the *Abandoned* page on the wiki, so I expect that that package is no longer available.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jaskirat Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/30755/jaskirat-singh/) on 2017-06-20**:
So if I have to install trex, what should I do now ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-20**:
I'm afraid I can't help you with that. You could try and search with Google or some other search engine to see if you can find someone who has a fork / copy of it somewhere.